# Create a friend sub-collection in the Users collection, Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a "User" collection whose registration method is as follows:

```
public class UserHelper  {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "USERTABLE";

    public  static CollectionReference getUserCollection(){
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public static Task<Void> createUser(String uid, String email, String password, String pseudo, String photo_url,boolean statut){
        Usermodele usermodele = new Usermodele(uid,email,password,pseudo,photo_url,statut);

        return UserHelper.getUserCollection().document(uid).set(usermodele);
    }
```

To this class, I want to create a subcollection "AmisHelper", I did this to create the subcollection but it seems that some things are not going.

```
public class AmiHelper {

    private static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "AMISCOLLECTION";

    public static CollectionReference getAmiCollection(){
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public static Task<Void> createAmi(String idDemandeur, String idReceveur, String pseudo, String photo_url, String date_amitie){
        AmisModele amisModele = new AmisModele(idDemandeur,idReceveur,pseudo,photo_url,date_amitie);

        return UserHelper.getUserCollection().document(idDemandeur).collection("AMISCOLLECTION").document(idReceveur).set(amisModele);
    }
```

And when in use, I did this

```
        holder.boutonAjouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "clic position"+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             UserHelper.getUserCollection().document(uid).collection("AMISCOLLECTION").document(uid).set(uid,uid,"","","");
            }
        });
```

I probably did something abnormal

When I click on the "Add" button I have this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Data must be a Map<String, Object> or a suitable POJO object, but it was of type: java.lang.String
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:234)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseSetData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:166)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:146)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.add(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.1:121)
        at com.devolab.recapitulatif.adapter.TabAbonneAdapter$1.onClick(TabAbonneAdapter.java:79)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Data must be a Map, or a suitable POJO object, but it was of type: java.lang.String

Because you are trying to write to a document a String value, which is actually not possible. According to the official documentation regarding [set() method parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#set(java.lang.Object)):

> The data to write to the document (e.g. a Map or a POJO containing the desired document contents).

So there is no way you can simply write a String, hence that error. To solve this is issue, pass to the set() method a Map containing as a key the name of the property and as a value the actual value of that String. The schema should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- USERTABLE (collection)
         |
         --- uid (document)
              |
              --- AMISCOLLECTION (collection)
                     |
                     --- uid (document)
                          |
                          --- fieldName: "StringValue"
```

You can also use an object of your POJO class, as you already did in the first two shared examples.

Comment: Yes  Alex Mamo, your answer allowed me to review my way of recording. Actu I am looking for a way to retrieve the user id on which I clicked. That is to say I have a recyclerview and I want to recover the id of the one on which a click was made. Thank you